# How to change location (x,y) of an object with VB.NET in UWP?

Tags: vb.net, windows, uwp

I have from the begin a Picturebox and i want to move it over the screen but something like
`image.location = new Point(x,y);` or `image.location.x = value;`  do not work. I have searching the half web and i can't find anything about that and in the documentation of Microsoft i can't find something. It could be that i am not find the correct words to use it in google

Comment: Maybe you could post the code that is in question, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to Windows Forms where the control were laid out in absolute coordinates globally, for UWP and WPF it really depends on the container where the control is located. If the control is inside a `Grid` it's layout depends on the row and column where it lies. To control the absolute coordinates, you have to place it inside a `Canvas` and then set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image ... />
</Canvas>
```

Now in code you can do something along the lines of:

```
image.SetValue( Canvas.LeftProperty, x );
image.SetValue( Canvas.TopProperty, y );
```

Alternatively you can use `TranslateTransform` to move the control relatively to its default calculated position.

Comment: thanks with the `image.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,x);` command do it work